# Recommended continuous integeration system for Git?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, dvcs

I am trying to find any recommended continuous integration systems for Git,
I have found plugins for Cruisecontrol etc, 
but I thought there would be some software around that are specifically built around the way and common workflows involved with Git (e.g. executing tests for each branch or similar functionality)

We are in particular looking for using the ci software together with PHP and JavaScript, perhaps Java as well, all on Linux systems.

Any pointers in the right direction would be great!

Comment: We use Hudson in our free hosted CI platform: [fazend.com](http://www.fazend.com). You can get your CI environment there without a necessity to install Hudson in-house.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im using [Jenkins-PHP](http://jenkins-php.org/) and CruiseControl/[phpUnderControl](http://phpundercontrol.org/). I'm happy with that.

Answer (score 2):

I have to recommend [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) purely because of the amount of plugins it has, the community support and the ease of extending it (by writing your own plugins).  It is also the easiest to install and administer that I have come accross.

The price is good as well (free).

Comment: As back up to the 'community support' a quote from [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_%28software%29) is interesting: "The project was forked from Hudson after a dispute with Oracle. ... As of 22 January 2013, The Jenkins organisation on GitHub had 431 project members and 890 public repositories, Hudson 33 project members and 82 public repositories"

Answer (score 1):

I've used CruiseControl.rb, but it seems to suffer from some stability under high load. I have heard good things about (the Oracle flavored) Hudson and/or (FOSS-flavored) [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/). Our dev-team is currently investigating switching over to it.

If you have a complex branch flow in your development cycle, you might look into git hooks to and the APIs that the various CI servers provide. The [Jenkins remote access api](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API) seems like it might be able to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is by far the best CI server I've used and it's free for small to medium sized teams.

Details of Git configuration are here - http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Git+%28JetBrains%29